# Does g++ empty function removal work recursively?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

To the best of my knowledge, `g++` with optimization turned on will remove the function call to `bar` entirely in the following case:

```
int bar() { }    
int foo() { bar(); }
```

However, consider the following two cases, with `bar` defined as above:

Case 1:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) bar();
}
```

Case 2:

```
int foo() { bar(); }
int foo2() {foo(); }
```

In Case 1, will the `if` statement also be removed, since it executes dead code even if the condition is true?

In Case 2:, will the call to `foo` inside `foo2` be removed?

Comment: look at the disassembly. It isn't that hard to see.

Comment: Did you know you can try it and see?  For example, using GCC's -S option to compile but not assemble, then you will be able to read fairly easily what it is doing.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I will try that. I was originally hesitant about disas because I wasn't sure what to look for, since I would guess the compiler would inline.

Comment: In short, you can expect all that code to be removed, but nothing's guaranteed.  The Standard allows scope for optimisations, but doesn't in general specify when they must be applied.  So, your question can best be answered in terms of `g++`'s observed behaviours - given your question has that tag.  What happens depends on versions and compiler flags - why don't you try for yourself?  Separately "dead code" refers to code which could never execute due to the branch conditions for execution being impossible to satisfy at run-time: you just have an empty function, not dead code.

Comment: Keep in mind that, whatever you find out, might be very different with the next version of g++, or on different hardware.

Comment: @merlin2011 for such a small program, the code will be short. even not knowing what to look for exactly, you should probably be able to figure it out.

Comment: @merlin2011: "I wasn't sure what to look for, since I would guess the compiler would inline" - an inlined empty function leaves nothing to look for - you can just check to see if `foo` still exists, and if so whether it does an integer comparison before returning.  You've said the return type's `int` but have no `return` statement....

Comment: Note that what you see there is not a dedicated "dead code removal" but a side-effect of inlining no-ops.

Comment: @TonyD, good point, although the compiler does not seem to complain about the lack of return statement.

Comment: @merlin2011: It should complain: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43b86079d183c028. Have you remembered to enable warnings?

Comment: @merlin2011 “the compiler does not seem to complain about the lack of return statement”: you should use the compiler flag `-Wall` (and `-Wextra`, in addition to `-std=c++11` and `-pedantic-errors`...)

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I tried this myself and it appears that the empty function calls **are indeed removed recursively and completely** in both cases I described, at least for `gcc 4.8.1` and `g++ 4.8.1`.

I compiled the following two programs, first with `gcc -S` and then with `gcc -S -O2`.

Program 1:

```
int bar() { }
int foo() { bar(); }
int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Program 2:

```
int bar() { }

int foo(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) bar();
}

int main() {
    foo(2,1);
}
```

I also tried with `foo`'s arguments passed in from the command line, to make sure the removal was not because of constants passed to `foo`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo(argc,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't remove entire functions, the linker does.

If you're building an executable (or the functions are not exported out of a library), then the linker will remove all the orphan functions. If it doesn't, it's a bug :).

BTW, storing the address of a function (e.g. in a variable or passing it to another function) guaranties that the function will stay.

**Edit**
Just, to be clear, the optimizing compiler will inline functions, effectively removing the function calls where it deems necessary. In the above case (super simple functions) there's no doubt it will inline them. BTW, STL implementations (and boost) depend on this feature heavily.

Comment: This is not about removing *functions*, but about removing *calls*.

Comment: Unless disabling this feature, the compiler inlines simple functions, removing the calls. I'll update the answer